# How to update org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have emacs 28.1 (released on Apr 4, 2022) installed through [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/). When I do `M-x org-version` it says Org-mode version 9.3.4 (which is more than two years old), when the latest version is 9.5 (7 months old). Org-mode documentation says that in order to upgrade org-mode you have to do `M-x list-packages` and select `org` package, but there is no `org` package in my list... I need org latest version in order to use org-cite-insert. How can I upgrade my org-mode (without GitHub if possible)?

Comment: After 9.5, Org is available on [GNU ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org.html). Have you changed the value of `package-archives`? Besides, on my side, the built in org of emacs 28.1 on my side is 9.5.2

Comment: Here is my config for  Package Repositories:

`(require 'package)`

`(setq package-archives`

`(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")`

`("gnu-devel" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/")`

`("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/")`

`("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))`

Comment: Problem solved, I did `sudo snap remove emacs` deleted `~/.emacs.d/` and then `sudo snap install emacs`.